# Why is 'Comparator.comparingInt' not working the same as 'new Comparator'?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have been working on an algorithm question from leetcode. The question is 313. Super Ugly Number.
Quetion description is

> A super ugly number is a positive integer whose prime factors are in the array primes.
>
> Given an integer n and an array of integers primes, return the nth super ugly number.
>
> The nth super ugly number is guaranteed to fit in a 32-bit signed integer.

My submission failed one case. The case is n = 5911 and primes = [2,3,5,7].
Below is my code, you can see I used `Comparator.comparingInt` instead of `new Comparator` as advised by IDEA. The result is -2147483648.

```
    public int nthSuperUglyNumber(int n, int[] primes) {
        int[] rets = new int[n];
        PriorityQueue<PrimeCandidate> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(primes.length, Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.num));
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) priorityQueue.offer(new PrimeCandidate(primes[i], primes[i], 1));
        rets[0] = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            rets[i] = priorityQueue.peek().num;
            while(priorityQueue.peek().num == rets[i]) {
                PrimeCandidate droppedPrimecandidate = priorityQueue.poll();
                priorityQueue.offer(new PrimeCandidate(rets[droppedPrimecandidate.index]*droppedPrimecandidate.prime
                        , droppedPrimecandidate.prime, droppedPrimecandidate.index+1));
            }
        }
        return rets[n-1];
    }

    class PrimeCandidate {
        int num;
        int prime;
        int index;
        PrimeCandidate(int num, int prime, int index) {
            this.num = num;
            this.prime = prime;
            this.index = index;
        }
    }
```

However, after I changed back to `new Comparator`, the result was correct which is 2144153025.

```
 public int nthSuperUglyNumber(int n, int[] primes) {
        int[] rets = new int[n];
        PriorityQueue<PrimeCandidate> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(primes.length, new Comparator<PrimeCandidate>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(PrimeCandidate o1, PrimeCandidate o2) {
                return o1.num - o2.num;
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) priorityQueue.offer(new PrimeCandidate(primes[i], primes[i], 1));
        rets[0] = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            rets[i] = priorityQueue.peek().num;
            while(priorityQueue.peek().num == rets[i]) {
                PrimeCandidate droppedPrimecandidate = priorityQueue.poll();
                priorityQueue.offer(new PrimeCandidate(rets[droppedPrimecandidate.index]*droppedPrimecandidate.prime
                        , droppedPrimecandidate.prime, droppedPrimecandidate.index+1));
            }
        }
        return rets[n-1];
    }

    class PrimeCandidate {
        int num;
        int prime;
        int index;
        PrimeCandidate(int num, int prime, int index) {
            this.num = num;
            this.prime = prime;
            this.index = index;
        }
    }
```

What's the reasons behind it. I thought the two methods are equivalent.

- Idea suggests using 'Comparator.comparingInt' to replace 'new Comparator'.
- I googled the usage of `Comparator.comparingInt` and the source code.
  All implied that the two are working the same way. But it was not in my case.

Comment: "*the two are working the same way*" which two? `a - b` and `comparintInt()` ?? I cannot believe that, pretty sure that `comparingInt` is using `Integer.compare()`, which in turn uses `?:` to return the correct value from `-1`, `0`, and `+1`

Comment: For reference, the LeetCode problem is https://leetcode.com/problems/super-ugly-number/ .

Answer (score 2):

No, the two are not the same. `Comparator.comparingInt` is correct and `a - b` is wrong.

The problem is integer overflow.

Imagine comparing -5 and 2. That should, obviously, return a negative number (-5 is 'before' 2). Either one will do just that. `a - b` returns a negative number, and the comparator made by `Comparator.comparingInt(a -> -5 or 2)` also would.

But now imagine comparing -2^31-1 and 20. This should also return a negative number, for the same reason. However, `a - b` would **return a positive number** due to overflow.

This is one of the reasons why you should **never** use `a - b` as implementation for a comparator function (and why you should heed linter tool advice and use `comparingInt` and friends which get it right - you're going to have to write `if (a < b) return -1;` etc if you do it by hand).

Weirdly, that would mean you'd expect `Comparator.comparingInt` to give the right answer and `a - b` to fail.

It's possible the checker at leetcode was written with the same bug (as in, their impl also has the bug and therefore actually marks as correct code with the identical bug in it, and marks as 'incorrect' a correct impl).

Given that you know the test case that fails just run both and check by hand which one has the right answer (you can use wolfram alpha to split a number into primes if you need). Then you know or at least you can check how these 2 differ specifically for the known problematic input.

Comment: I think leetcode might be correct. `rets[droppedPrimecandidate.index]*droppedPrimecandidate.prime` in OP's code overflows too, which I guess "cancels out" the overflow problem with the `a - b` comparator.